# Which community to post a question on the design and implementation of Automatic Differentiation

Tags: discussion, design, site-recommendation, algorithm, optimization

I am looking to post a question (composed of 4 smaller and related questions) pertaining to the theory, implementation and definition of an algorithm to differentiate mathematical expressions, namely, the Automatic Differentiation (AD) technique.

The topic borders the following themes:

- Definitions and algorithms (what AD is and what it is not and
  contradictions I have found in various sources) Mathematics
  (questions on the Calculus behind it) Algorithms (the steps to solve
  AD) Software design and implementation (trade off's of AD compared to
  other differentiation techniques, i.e. speed vs simplicity).

I was thinking of posting it on Stack Overflow because:

- It is the most generic of communities if I had to choose amongst the
  others. A lot of questions are already numerical in nature and have
  mathematical implementations (or mathematical theory behind it) Many
  SO posts also contain the benefits/costs of implementation

Should I consider posting on another community?

Comment: Could you just *post the question*, so you can get specific feedback?

Comment: @jonrsharpe and risk avalanche of downvotes, closure, and question ban, if the question is deemed "too broad", "lacking a minimal verifiable code" etc. (on SO, as an example) ? :)

Comment: @WillNess sorry, I meant include it in the post *here*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, makes sense, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: you can try googling around, see where your kind of questions are mostly asked, and ask there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, will edit the OP soon to include the actual post